# WITH Recursive query is not working when run using entityManager native query

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I'm running this PostgreSQL query on Java and it is throwing an error "ERROR: syntax error at or near ":".
But the query is working on Postgresql when I run directly.
I'm thinking Array[]::integer[] is causing the issue. Can someone has any idea?

```java
String query = "WITH RECURSIVE tree AS ( SELECT id, ARRAY[]::integer[] AS ancestors \n" +
                "  FROM regions \n" +
                "  WHERE parent_id IS NULL\n" +
                "  UNION ALL \n" +
                "  SELECT soato.id, tree.ancestors || regions.parent_id \n" +
                "  FROM regions, tree \n" +
                "  WHERE regions.parent_id = tree.id \n" +
                ") \n" +
                "  SELECT d.id FROM department d \n" +
                "  WHERE d.region_id IN (select id from tree where 1703 = ANY(tree.ancestors))";
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
q.getResultList();
```

Comment: Use an explicit CAST instead of :: . ARRAY[CAST(NULL AS INTEGER)] AS ancestors

Comment: @FrankHeikens yes, that worked. Can you post your answer as an answer so I could mark it as a correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an explicit cast to avoid the implicit PostgreSQL option :: for casting.

```
ARRAY[CAST(NULL AS INTEGER)] AS ancestors
```